# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

i am getting this error when i am trying to run an emotion detection program via annaconda but it shows this error but when i run on jupyter notebook its working fine. help.

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'


Traceback:
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 338, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Aman\emotion.py", line 2, in <module>
    from deepface import DeepFace
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py", line 15, in <module>
    from deepface.basemodels import VGGFace, OpenFace, Facenet, FbDeepFace, DeepID, DlibWrapper, ArcFace, Boosting
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\deepface\basemodels\Boosting.py", line 8, in <module>
    from deepface.commons import functions, distance as dst
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\deepface\commons\functions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mtcnn import MTCNN #0.1.0
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\mtcnn.py", line 37, in <module>
    from mtcnn.network.factory import NetworkFactory
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\network\factory.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, PReLU, Flatten, Softmax
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import initializers
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    populate_deserializable_objects()
File "c:\users\aman\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 49, in populate_deserializable_objects
    LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf.__internal__.tf2.enabled()
```

Comment: The above issue was due to incompatibility between `Tensorflow` and `Keras` version. It can be resolved either by upgrade `keras` to `Keras2.5.0rc0` and `import keras` or import `keras` from `tensorflow` as `from tensorflow import keras`.For more information you can refer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817124/14290681). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can properly format your Issue, we can identify what is actually happening

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem.

i am using anaconda and jupyter-lab in an virtual environment created like this:
conda create -n tf.
source activete tf.
conda install tensorflow-gpu.
conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.10.0 #if you want to install 1.10.0 version conda install tensorflow #if you want to install cpu version.
import tensorflow as tf tf. **version**

my code looks like this:
import os
import sys
import json
import datetime
import numpy as np
import skimage.draw
import cv2

from mrcnn.visualize import display_instances
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("C:/Users/domiw/OneDrive/Desktop/Zach/Anaconda/tuts/1/wastedata-Mask_RCNN-multiple-classes/main/Mask_RCNN")

sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)

from mrcnn.config import Config

from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils

........ here comes the error:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute '**internal**'

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error message after upgrading Tensorflow to version 2.7.0 . Downgrading the library to 2.5.0 is a temporary working fix.
Note: I previously tried all the solutions provided in the answers in this same post and also in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67696519/module-tensorflow-compat-v2-internal-has-no-attribute-tf2)

`pip install tensorflow==2.5.0`