# module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'tf2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to use TensorFlow as backend yesterday I can use it, but today when I use it to show some error message when I'm trying to import Keras, so here's my code:

```
# Install required libs  
# NOTE: Run this one code, then restart this runtime and run again for next all... (PENTING!!!) 
 
### please update Albumentations to version>=0.3.0 for `Lambda` transform support
!pip install -U segmentation-models

!pip install q tensorflow==2.1
!pip install q keras==2.3.1
!pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1.

## Imports libs
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'


import cv2
import Keras
import NumPy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

it shows this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-9c78a7be919d> in <module>()
      5 
      6 import cv2
----> 7 import keras
      8 import numpy as np
      9 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

8 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/initializers/__init__.py in populate_deserializable_objects()
     47 
     48   LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS = {}
---> 49   LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf.__internal__.tf2.enabled()
     50 
     51   # Compatibility aliases (need to exist in both V1 and V2).

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'tf2'
```

while therefore I was using TensorFlow version 2.2 and Keras version 2.3.1, yesterday I can run, but today it seems can't. did I was the wrong version import for my Keras and TensorFlow for today?

Edit:
when I use `from tensorFlow import keras` the output I want `using tensorflow backend` doesn't show up, And then when I load `import segmentation_models as sm` it shows the same error when I use `import Keras` like on above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem, I've tested it on colab.

```
!pip install -U -q segmentation-models
!pip install -q tensorflow==2.1
!pip install -q keras==2.3.1
!pip install -q tensorflow-estimator==2.1.

## Imports libs
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"

from tensorflow import keras
import segmentation_models as sm
```

```
|████████████████████████████████| 51kB 3.3MB/s 
|████████████████████████████████| 421.8MB 42kB/s 
|████████████████████████████████| 450kB 35.7MB/s 
|████████████████████████████████| 3.9MB 33.6MB/s 
Building wheel for gast (setup.py) ... done
ERROR: tensorflow-probability 0.12.1 has requirement gast>=0.3.2, 
but you'll have gast 0.2.2 which is incompatible.
|████████████████████████████████| 378kB 2.1MB/s 
Segmentation Models: using `tf.keras` framework.
```

---

### Update

You **don't need to install** any specific version of `tensorflow / keras`. **Any version above `2.x` would be ok to run, i.e `tf 2.4/ 2.5/ 2.6`**. However, in colab, you need to restart the kernel to see the effect. but if you run on the kaggle kernel, you don't need to restart the kernel. See below:

**In colab:**

```
# Cell: 1
import os 
!pip install -U -q segmentation-models --user
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

It will **auto-restart** the kernel. After restarting, run the following code in the new cell.

```
#Cell: 2
import os 
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"
import segmentation_models as sm
```

**In Kaggle Kernel:**

```
import os 
!pip install -U -q segmentation-models --user
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"
import segmentation_models as sm
```

Comment: may I know, why when I load from import Keras I cant use the TensorFlow backend? and why the output using TensorFlow backend not come? or I must use tf.Keras not Keras?

Comment: After `tf 2.x`, the standalone `keras` is no longer maintained and it became a part of `tf`. So, previously we use `import keras` and now (after `tf .2.x`, we should use `from ten.. import keras`. As you are using `tf 2.`, you should import that way.

Comment: The reason for not showing `TensorFlow backend` is because in old `keras` it has three backed, and one of them was `tf` (AFAIK) but after `tf 2.x`, there is only one backed, which is `tf`, so that message is now depreciated

Comment: You also have the error if you have `tensorflow==2.7.0` and `keras==2.8.0`. Forcing keras to 2.7.0 solves the problem!

Comment: For me, the error was TensorFlow and Keras were different versions. I had to ensure that both were the same version.

Answer (score 5):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

print(tf.__version__, keras.__version__)

output: 2.7.0 2.7.0
```

I tried a lot of answers but none of them worked for me.
The reason of the error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.**internal**.distribute' has no attribute 'strategy_supports_no_merge_call'
in my case was that I had tensorflow 2.7.0 and keras 2.6.0 installed on my device.

```
output while getting this error: 2.7.0 2.6.0
```

just match the versions, it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks like the Arch repositories currently have such a version mismatch.

Comment: That script literally stack traces for me, the minute i try to import keras.

Answer (score 2):

specifying below, before importing segmentation models,  alone worked for me in colab

```
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error message after upgrading Tensorflow to 2.7.0 . Downgrading to 2.5.0 is a temporary working fix.

`pip install tensorflow==2.5.0`

Comment: did you use `os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"`? I thought it's ok for now using any version of `tf 2.x`

Comment: I tried that and got the same error message, nothing changed